# Can netty events be prioritized (to the head of the event queue)

Tags: netty

I am working on a project which requires publish/subscribe functionality and is using Netty (4.1.48). We have two event groups - a *worker* event group that handles all incoming commands and a *subscriber* event group that handles sending published messages to subscribers. Initially, subscription requests are processed by *workers*. Before responding to the client, a subscription request is deregistered and registered to the *subscriber* group. This happens asynchronously and is performed entirely by the *worker* (both `deregister` and subsequent `register` in the future call). It can thus happen that when a publish command arrives, the subscriber is still on the *worker* group and has not yet been moved to the *subscriber* group. I *really* need the `deregister()` call to happen synchronously or, at least, to be prioritized so that it is the very next event that the current event loop will process. Is it possible to do that?

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 0):

No its not... events are executed in the same order as submitted to the EventLoop for execution

Comment: I was afraid of that - thanks for responding though.